# Lmfit error while fitting with a power law : invalid value encountered in multiply return

Tags: python, lmfit

Lmfit fails to do a fit with a power law-type function and I really can't grasp why.

The function is the following

```py
def HB(x, ys, K, n):
    return ys + K*np.power(x, n)
```

The data I try to fit is this one :

```py
rate = [1.00e-04, 1.33e-04, 1.76e-04, 2.33e-04, 3.09e-04, 4.09e-04,
       5.43e-04, 7.20e-04, 9.54e-04, 1.26e-03, 1.68e-03, 2.22e-03,
       2.95e-03, 3.91e-03, 5.18e-03, 6.87e-03, 9.10e-03, 1.21e-02,
       1.60e-02, 2.12e-02, 2.81e-02, 3.73e-02, 4.94e-02, 6.55e-02,
       8.68e-02, 1.15e-01, 1.53e-01, 2.02e-01, 2.68e-01, 3.56e-01,
       4.71e-01, 6.25e-01, 8.29e-01, 1.10e+00, 1.46e+00, 1.93e+00,
       2.56e+00, 3.39e+00, 4.50e+00, 5.96e+00, 7.91e+00, 1.00e+01,
       1.05e+01, 1.27e+01, 1.39e+01, 1.62e+01, 1.84e+01, 2.07e+01,
       2.44e+01, 2.64e+01, 3.24e+01, 3.36e+01, 4.28e+01, 4.29e+01,
       5.46e+01, 5.69e+01, 6.95e+01, 7.54e+01, 8.86e+01, 1.00e+02,
       1.13e+02, 1.44e+02, 1.83e+02, 2.34e+02, 2.98e+02, 3.79e+02,
       4.83e+02, 6.16e+02, 7.85e+02, 1.00e+03]

stress = [   8.25,    8.9 ,    9.19,    9.29,    9.32,    9.46,    9.58,
          9.59,    9.82,   10.  ,   10.2 ,   10.4 ,   10.6 ,   10.8 ,
         11.1 ,   11.4 ,   11.8 ,   12.2 ,   12.7 ,   13.2 ,   13.8 ,
         14.5 ,   15.3 ,   16.2 ,   17.2 ,   18.5 ,   19.9 ,   21.4 ,
         23.3 ,   25.3 ,   27.8 ,   30.5 ,   33.8 ,   37.6 ,   42.1 ,
         47.2 ,   53.2 ,   60.2 ,   68.4 ,   77.9 ,   89.  ,   93.9 ,
        102.  ,  106.  ,  117.  ,  120.  ,  135.  ,  136.  ,  156.  ,
        154.  ,  180.  ,  175.  ,  199.  ,  208.  ,  226.  ,  242.  ,
        258.  ,  283.  ,  294.  ,  331.  ,  337.  ,  387.  ,  446.  ,
        515.  ,  597.  ,  695.  ,  812.  ,  950.  , 1120.  , 1330.  ]
```

Both fields have absolutely no negative values. I fix bounds like so :

```py
HB_model = lmfit.Model(HB)
HB_model.set_param_hint('ys', min=5, max=20)
HB_model.set_param_hint('K', min=1e-6, max=100)
HB_model.set_param_hint('n', min=0.4, max=0.8)
```

And I know by trial and error that a really good guess is around ys=10, K=20, and n=0.6, which looks like this once plotted :

[image: trial and error "fit"]

Although, when doing the fit with

```py
res_fit=HB_model.fit(stress,x=rate)
```

I get the following error message

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply return ys + K*np.power(x, n)

And both values for ys and K change while n is systematically equal to the lower bound I impose.
Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: I don't think this is anything to worry about. But the actual cause is because you don't an initial value for the parameters. This is always a good, in particular if you have a decent idea of the actual value (or you use a value in the (log)mid range of the boundaries, since you set those). Set an initial value with e.g. `HB_model.set_param_hint('n', value=0.6, min=0.4, max=0.8)`.

Comment: If you don't set an initial value for a param, [the starting default value is NaN](https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/blob/master/lmfit/model.py#L612), which obviously throws a warning (doing operation with a NaN value will do that), which is what you are seeing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted at in the comment by @9769953, the problem is almost certainly that you did not provide initial values.  Oddly, you say that you have
good initial values and show a plot using them.  So, just do

```
HB_model = lmfit.Model(HB)
params = HB_model.make_params(ys=10, K=20, n=0.6)
```

I would advise against setting bounds as you have with `Model.set_param_hint()`.  First, don't set bounds too tightly because you think those "ought to be close".  Set bounds to prevent absurd values or to prevent NaNs from being generated.
Second, setting parameter hints is **for the model**, and it is just not correct to say that a power-law model should have an offset between 5 and 20.  It *might* be reasonable (bu probably isn't) to say that a certain data set fit to that power-law model should have the offset constrained between 5 and 20.   But, it is better to do that with the Parameters to be used for that data set, not for the model in general.  So, perhaps something like this:

```
HB_model = lmfit.Model(HB)
params = HB_model.make_params(ys=10, K=20, n=0.6)
params['ys'].max = 100
params['ys'].min = 0
params['K'].min = 0
params['n'].min = 0

result = HB_model.fit(stress, params, x=rate)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was all confused by the bounds.